# React + WebSockets App architecture problem

Tags: reactjs, websocket

There is a server that sends WebSocket messages. First when you connect it sends back list of topics: `{type: 'INDEX', payload: ['topic-1', 'topic-2', 'topic-3']}`. And then it sends some numeric value for each topic with various intervals: `{type: 'UPDATE', payload: { topic: 'topic-3', value: 7}}`

My React app uses custom hook to receive messages and decides what to to with it:

```
const [topics, setTopics] = useState([])

useWebSocket('ws://localhost:4000', (action) => {
    const { type, payload } = action

    switch (type) {
        case 'INDEX':
            setTopics(payload)
            break
        case 'UPDATE':
            console.log('UPDATE', payload)
            // ???
            break
        default:
            break
    }
})

return (
    <ul>
        {topics.map(topic => <Topic key={topic} name={topic} value={???} />)}
    </ul>
)
```

My problem is that i can't decide how to send and update numeric value at each `<Topic />` individually without re-rendering whole component. Do i need to create some sort of array of states for each topic?

Topic component just renders `<li>{name}: [{value}]</li>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you want to pass the WebSocket data down, you have to store it in a state (or use an external store library like Zustand, that would work too).

It will re-render the whole component, but re-rendering *is fine* most of the time. If it takes too long, you can memoize the `Topic` component, then only the one concerned with the update will re-render.

Also, is your `useWebSocket` hook creating a websocket connection ? I would recommend if you need a very scalable architecure to create the websocket connection in a context provider, and have a context consumer hook (let's say `useWebSocket`) that sets up a listener on that connection. Therefore you could directly call `useWebsocket` inside the `Topic` component without creating one connection per topic.